# Какие есть применения у this в Java?

Tags: java, this

Я знаю он возвращает ссылку на текущий объект, и с его помощью можно разрешить конфликт локальных и глобальных имен, например в конструкторе. Но какие есть более практичные применения?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "более практичными применениями"?

Comment: Вообще любые применения, которые могут быть полезны в реальном коде. Ведь обычно (насколько я понимаю) вместо this можно использовать просто имя объекта, а в тех же конструкторах просто избегать конфликта имен.

Comment: Как использовать имя объекта, например, в геттере?

Comment: С помощью this, например, вы можете вызвать другой конструктор из конструктора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем применение оператора this можно обобщить до следующего:

1. Обращение к не статичным полям класса.
2. Получение текущего объекта.
3. Для решения конфликтов локальных и глобальных.
4. Вызов другого конструктора из конструктора.

К примерам. Использование this в конструкторе:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int old;

    Person(String name, int old){
        this.name = name;//Здесь мы получаем доступ к не статичному полю класса
        this.old = old; // Здесь мы получаем доступ полю класса
    }
}
```

Здесь мы получаем доступ к не статичному полям класса. В методах типа equals ():

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Person){
        Person obj1 = (Person) obj;
        if(this.name.equals(obj1) &&
                this.id == obj1.id &&
                this.old == obj1.old)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Для создания потока:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    String name;
    Thread t;

    public MyThread(String name){
        this.name = name;
        t=new Thread(this); /* Здесь мы передаем экземпляр класса,
                              в котором будут разворачиваются действо. */
        t.setName(name);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(name+": "+i);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Для получения аннотаций:

```
Annotation [] getAnnotation (){
    return this.getClass().getAnnotations();
}
```

И множество других примеров использования.

Answer (score 6):

Например паттерн Builder почти во всех методах для возврата того же объекта использует везде this.

Answer (score 0):

Например, когда внутри метода текущего объекта класса нужно передать текущий объект (`this`) в метод другого класса.

Пример:

```
class Example {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.moveTo(1, 1);
        System.out.println(p); // 1x1
        
        Utils.plus(p, 2, -1);
        System.out.println(p); // 3x0
    }
}

class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    
    public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
        Utils.plus(this, x, y);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%sx%s", x, y);
    }
}

class Utils {
    public static void plus(Point p1, int x, int y) {
        p1.x += x;
        p1.y += y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к начинке внутренних нестатических классов: Vehicle.this.run();...